# Trigger onchange function after component is rendered

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a problem with triggering a function on the lightning-combobox. Everything works fine in onchange action, but is there any way how to trigger that same function, when the components is loaded?

I just simply wants to call function `supplyLength` as soon as the combobox is rendered. Not after changing the value in it.

Thanks for any help.

```
<lightning-combobox name="powerSupply"
    class="powerSupplyCable"
    label="Select Power Supply cable"
    value={value}
    options={types}
    onchange={supplyLength}>
</lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Its part of dependent picklist. Based on value from powerSupply combobox, there is limited values in another picklist. But when i open window, value in powerSupply is preselected and in dependent picklist not. Thats what my function "supplyLength" doing. Selecting value in picklist is limiting values in second picklist.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a method from renderedCallback() to do things that happen after the page has re-rendered. Please note that this may cause infinite loops if you update elements that would then be re-rendered again. Make sure you only make changes if necessary (use if statements).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @sfdcfox's answer, it's pretty common to use a runtime variable with `renderedCallback()` to run something once on initial load, but not on every subsequent rerender.  Rerendering happens a lot, and this pattern also mitigates the risk of infinite loops.

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class MyApp extends LightningElement {
    ranOnce = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        // Always run supplyLength() on initial render
        if (!this.ranOnce) {
            this.supplyLength();
        }
        this.ranOnce = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I thought that would work but inside of my function supplyLength(), i am using event to access event.target.value